# Clicking an x button in selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

Here is the link to the site I am currently viewing: https://messari.io/tool/fb8d86ca-d3cf-4568-8d48-1a052c95364e. Scroll to the bottom of the page and click "View More".

I am trying to figure out how to click the x button but what I have tried hasn't worked. I get a "no such element: Unable to locate element error.

I have tried all three of these:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "button").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@data-testid='CloseIcon')]").click()

driver.find_element_by_tag_name("svg").click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Xpath of the `load more` button `//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/button` -

[image: messari load more button xpath]

And then check the full Xpath of the `X` button that will close the pop-up window

[image: messari X button to close pop-up full xpath]

full Xpath of the `X` button - `'/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/h2/button'`

working code -

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
    options=options
)


def messari_scraper():
    URL = "https://messari.io/tool/fb8d86ca-d3cf-4568-8d48-1a052c95364e"
    with chrome_driver as driver:
        driver.implicitly_wait(15)  # wait max 15 sec for any element to find
        driver.get(URL)
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")  # scroll to the end of the page

        # click the button
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/button').click()

        time.sleep(3)

        # get the full Xpath of the close `x` button of the pop-up
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/h2/button').click()
        # pop up window closed

        time.sleep(5)

        # do your tasks here....


messari_scraper()
```

Comment: I have the view more button working on my scraper, but once you click on it, there is an x button in the top right of the pop-up window and that is what I can't get working

Comment: done, code updated